# How to apply pagination in youtube search list..?

Tags: youtube, pagination, youtube-api

i am working on youtube api and i want to apply pagination 
but i don't know how to do this 
i search on google and only get the information that i have to get the page token
but i dont know how to get page token
please help me to solve this problem
Thanks.

```
    <?php

$htmlBody = <<<END
<form method="GET">
  <div>
    Search Term: <input type="search" id="q" name="q" placeholder="Enter Search Term">
  </div>
  <div>
    Max Results: <input type="number" id="maxResults" name="maxResults" min="1" max="50" step="1" value="25">
  </div>
  <input type="submit" value="Search">

</form>
END;

// This code will execute if the user entered a search query in the form
// and submitted the form. Otherwise, the page displays the form above.
if ($_GET['q'] && $_GET['maxResults']) {
  // Call set_include_path() as needed to point to your client library.
  require_once ($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].'/youtube/google-api-php-client/src/Google_Client.php');
  require_once ($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].'/youtube/google-api-php-client/src/contrib/Google_YouTubeService.php');

  /*
   * Set $DEVELOPER_KEY to the "API key" value from the "Access" tab of the
   * Google Developers Console <https://console.developers.google.com/>
   * Please ensure that you have enabled the YouTube Data API for your project.
   */
  $DEVELOPER_KEY = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';

  $client = new Google_Client();
  $client->setDeveloperKey($DEVELOPER_KEY);

  // Define an object that will be used to make all API requests.
  $youtube = new Google_YoutubeService($client);

  try {
    // Call the search.list method to retrieve results matching the specified
    // query term.
    $searchResponse = $youtube->search->listSearch('id,snippet', array(
      'q' => $_GET['q'],
      'maxResults' => '10',
    ));

    $videos = '';
    $channels = '';
    $playlists = '';

    // Add each result to the appropriate list, and then display the lists of
    // matching videos, channels, and playlists.
    foreach ($searchResponse['items'] as $searchResult) {
      switch ($searchResult['id']['kind']) {
        case 'youtube#video':
          $videos .= sprintf('<a href=new/yt.php?videoid='.$searchResult['id']['videoId'].' target=_blank><li>%s (%s)</li>', $searchResult['snippet']['title'],
            $searchResult['id']['videoId']."   Watch This Video<br><img  src=' http://img.ytapi.com/vi/".$searchResult['id']['videoId']."/mqdefault.jpg' /></a>");
          break;
        case 'youtube#channel':
          $channels .= sprintf('<li>%s (%s)</li>',
              $searchResult['snippet']['title'], $searchResult['id']['channelId']);
          break;
        case 'youtube#playlist':
          $playlists .= sprintf('<li>%s (%s)</li>',
              $searchResult['snippet']['title'], $searchResult['id']['playlistId']);
          break;
      }
    }

    $htmlBody .= <<<END
    <h3>Videos</h3>
    <ul>$videos</ul>
    <h3>Channels</h3>
    <ul>$channels</ul>
    <h3>Playlists</h3>
    <ul>$playlists</ul>
END;
  } catch (Google_ServiceException $e) {
    $htmlBody .= sprintf('<p>A service error occurred: <code>%s</code></p>',
      htmlspecialchars($e->getMessage()));
  } catch (Google_Exception $e) {
    $htmlBody .= sprintf('<p>An client error occurred: <code>%s</code></p>',
      htmlspecialchars($e->getMessage()));
  }
  ?>
      <h1><a href="<?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ?>/<?php echo $searchResponse['nextPageToken'] ?>">next</a></h1>

<?php
}
?>

<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>YouTube Search</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <?=$htmlBody?>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The search response will return a "nextPageToken" and possibly a "prevPageToken" that can be passed with your next request (which, other than the changing page token, should be identical to the current request) to get a different set of data. You pass it with the "pageToken" parameter (not as part of the URL path as your code does here). So, for example, you could modify your search request to look like this:

```
$searchResponse = $youtube->search->listSearch('id,snippet', array(
  'q' => $_GET['q'],
  'maxResults' => '10',
  'pageToken' => $_GET['pageToken']
));
```

Then, you display your search results, and below that your "next" link should be modified like this:

```
<h1><a href="<?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ?>?q=<?php echo $_GET['q']>&pageToken=<?php echo $searchResponse['nextPageToken'] ?>">next</a></h1>
```